# PHP form in table not doing action

Tags: php, forms, action

It's got to be something easy I'm missing, maybe a " or ' is in the wrong place.  I have below code, and everything comes out great, the table is built and the "Delete" button is created, however when I click on the button it doesn't do anything, the button highlights but it just stays on the same page and doesn't go to my delete page, anyone see a problem with what I have below?

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>".'Show'."</th>";
echo "<th>".'TVDBID'."</th>";
echo "<th>".'AirsDayOfWeek'."</th>";
echo "<th>".'AirsTime'."</th>";
echo "<th>".'Status'."</th>";
echo "<th>".'Edit'."</th>";
echo "<tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($myShows)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['uShow']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['TVDBID']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['AirsDayOfWeek']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".strftime("%l:%M %p", strtotime($row['AirsTime']))."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['sStatus']."</td>";
    echo "<td><formb name=".$row['TVDBID']." action='DeleteShow.php?id=".$row['TVDBID']."'>"."<input type='submit' value='Delete'/></formb></td>";
    echo "<tr>";
}

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

**EDIT**

Adding the different forms from my CSS file, maybe I've missunderstood their use.

```
form {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.25em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

formb {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  text-align: center;
  padding: .25em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `formb` should be `form`?

Comment: I did it that way because I'm using the same CSS file for another page and the regular `form` adds extra padding that I didn't want.  However you are right, when I change it to `form` it does kickoff the delete page, but it doesn't pass the ID along with it.

Comment: You can just set some `id` for the form and then add it in the CSS. Using tags not understandable by the browser is not the way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replacing

```
echo "<td><formb name=".$row['TVDBID']." action='DeleteShow.php?id=".$row['TVDBID']."'>"."<input type='submit' value='Delete'/></formb></td>";
```

with

```
echo "<td><form name=".$row['TVDBID']." action='DeleteShow.php?id=".$row['TVDBID']." class='formb'>"."<input type='submit' value='Delete'/></form></td>";
```

Should work...

Update :

```
.formb {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  text-align: center;
  padding: .25em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

point is, call your CSS as `class` or `ID` over you `HTML FORM` element..

Comment: Yes, that does kick it over to the delete page, but what I replied to above is that I used a different form (formb) in my CSS file to get rid of the extra padding from the regular form, maybe I'm misunderstanding the use of the different styles in the CSS file.

Comment: try my code, I am sure, it will redirect you to 'DeleteShow.php' :)

Comment: You're absolutely right, it does.  However now for whatever reason it doesn't send the `id` over, its just sending a blank.

Comment: That works, but it doesn't seem to be taking the information from the .formb class, still taking it from the regular form (checked by changing the padding on both `form` and `.formb`)

Comment: you mean CSS in not being applied??

Comment: Correct, I modified `padding: .25em;` in `.formb` to something noticeable `padding: 3.25em;`, refreshed the page and nothing changed, however when I modified `padding: 1.25em;` in `form` to `padding: 3.25em;` it did change.

Comment: Its working now, was missing a `'`.  Now just got to figure out the deal with it not passing the ID with it.  Thanks a ton for sticking it out with me, never been really strong in HTML.